# How to pass parameters to a cucumber+maven project so they can be used in tests?

Tags: maven, cucumber

I need to be able to pass a username and password to my test suite when I run it. I'm not sure what's the best way to do so.

My project runs with Cucumber on Java, using Maven.

If it was just a java project I'd probably have a main method where I could get the parameters passed when project is executed. But since there's cucumber here, with its feature files and then some java classes for test implementation, I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose that you build your project using

```
mvn test
```

and now you want to add a user name and a password to the execution.

One way of doing this is

```
mvn test -DuserName=foo -Dpassword=bar
```

Where the user name is `foo` and the password `bar`.

Next task is to pick up the values in your code. This is done by reading system properties:

```
String userName = System.getProperty("userName");
String password = System.getProperty("password");
```

`userName` and `password` will be `null` if the values isn't passed properly.

Comment: Please share the exact command you used and details on how you determined that it didn't work.

Comment: I had missed some dependencies, after adding those it worked for me.

Comment: Happy to hear that you where able to understand and solve the issue.